# "command not found" when executing commands in mintty in Sublime text plugin Terminal

Tags: terminal, console, sublimetext3, putty, sublime-text-plugin

I'm trying to use Putty console through the Sublime Text plugin Terminal.
When I open it this way I can't to use Gulp.
When I open Putty directly - Gulp works correct.

How can I fix it?

Console output:

```
bash: cut: command not found

user@LenovoG510  ~/Desktop/Проекты учебные/Gulp/test_gulp/gulp and workflow (master)
$ gulp
/c/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/npm/gulp: line 2: sed: command not found
/c/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/npm/gulp: line 2: dirname: command not found
/c/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/npm/gulp: line 4: uname: command not found
module.js:472
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\Git\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:425:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:146:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:540:3
```

Settings of Sublime plugin Terminal

```
{
    // The command to execute for the terminal, leave blank for the OS default
    // See https://github.com/wbond/sublime_terminal#examples for examples
    "terminal": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin\\mintty.exe",
    "parameters": []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PuTTY opens an interactive shell session by default.

While `mintty.exe` (*what is not PuTTY console*) probably opens non-interactive session by default.

A different set of startup scripts is sources for interactive and non-interactive sessions. While in general the scripts should be configured in a way that the same environment variables (such as `PATH`) are set in both cases, it's no so in your account. You have to fix the startup scripts to set `PATH` correctly even for non-interactive sessions.